# Jquery draggable connect to many classes. how to identify which class?

Tags: jquery, draggable

I am using jquery draggable. The draggable connects to many classes. What I want to do is add different function to different class. Is it possible to identify which class it has been dropped?
Thanks in advance 
js:

```
$('#contentBasic').draggable({
          cursor: 'pointer',
          connectToSortable: '#onecolumn, #leftcolumn, #rightcolumn, #toprow, #firstcolumn, #secondcolumn',
          helper: 'clone',
          stop: function(event, ui){
            text.push($('#text_paragraph').html());
            saveLayout();
          } 
});
```

html:

```
ul id="contentBasic" class="droptrue" >       
          <li id="list_0">
            <div id="text_paragraph" contenteditable="true" class="contenteditable">
                Put your text here..
            </div>
                <input class="list_item_title" maxlength="250" type="text" id="list_4" style="display: none; ">
                <span class="drag-handle">Text</span>
          </li>
</ul>
```

What I want to do is, identify in which class the item stop. Thanks

Comment: Can you share your code so that we can have a look at that? html and js

Comment: ok I'll edit my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#dock").droppable({
     drop: function(event, ui) {
               // do something with the draggable item
               $(ui.draggable).doSomething();
           }
});
```

The second argument to drop callback is the droppable element.

Here the [docs](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/)